# Do statistical test with orange between data

Tags: orange

I'm learning orange and I'm looking to performe some statistical test on my data.
The test I usually do are z-test, t-test, chi-square test and Anova.
Can I use a widget to do these or should I do a python custom script ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I don't think Orange has anything like that. How would you design a widget for this? If seems a reasonable enhancement to have, why not submit them a feature proposal, or even a pull request? https://github.com/biolab/orange3

Comment: I thought about making a feature proposal but I didn't know if I was not able to find them because there not present or because I'm a beginner.

I'll make a issue on github, 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Box Plot gives a T-Test for two-group comparisons and Anova for > 2 group comparisons.

The Sieve Diagram gives a Chi2 test.